# Export to excel button implementation in Datatable

Tags: ajax, datatables

Hi I am trying to put export to excel buttons in my datatable but it not worked for me . can someone please help to get out of this problem.

Here is my js code....

```
    function Getpolicestationdetailsbylatlong(x, y) {


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Health.asmx/Getpolicestationdetailsbylatlong",
            data: "{'x':'" + x + "','y':" + y + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });

        function OnSuccess(data, status) {


            var myObject = JSON.parse(data.d);
            var source = {
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [

                    { name: 'district' },
                    { name: 'police_sta' }
                    //{ name: 'gid' }


                ],
                localdata: myObject
            };


            $('#example').DataTable(
                {


                    data: myObject,
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',

                    columns: [
                                   { 'data': 'district' },

                                   { 'data': 'police_sta' }



                    ],

                    buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
                    ]
});
```

and the html code is .....

```
<table id="example" class="display"  style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>DistrictName</th>
                <th>Policestation</th>



            </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
```

for the above code datatable is displaying but i didn't got export buttons.

Comment: You probably miss some of the `.js` prerequisities, like jszip, pdfmake etc.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @davidkonrad's comment, you are almost certainly missing the JsZip extension, which is required for the Excel export button to work with DataTables.

To quote from the DataTables download page:

> JSZip provides a method of creating zip files in pure Javascript. This library **must** be available on the page for the Excel button to operate.

As a side note, if your PDF button isn't working as well, it is probably because that button requires the PDFMake extension, although it sounds like only your Excel button is broken.